# IBM server shutdown and restart

Tags: linux, ups, power-supply-unit

How can I set up a server so that when there is a power cut it is safely shut down, and when  power returns it switches back on automatically?

I am specifically using an IBM AIX Server 6.

Comment: Bear in mind this often isn't the best idea unless done very carefully. If you have several machines which all turn back on at the same time, you run the risk of overloading your power. The more intelligent ups units turn servers back on in multiple stages, get one of those if possible.

Comment: oh and (from painful experience) check and double check that your air-con restarts automatically when power returns *before* you set your servers to turn back on and call the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to have a UPS (Uninterruptible Power Supply) for that, which sends a signal to the server when power is about to run out.

Comment: Also, there are likely BIOS settings that will allow you to have a server start when power returns.